# SSH Connection refused in virtual machine

Tags: ssh

I am running a virtual machine Phoenix, inside QEMU from [exploit.education](http://exploit.education) in Kali Linux. It is pre-installed with the newest version of OpenSSH; however, I get an error whenever I try to connect to the machine with SSH.
I used the command `ip a s` in my Kali machine. It displayed the following results:

```
$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:9a:60:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.12/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 85248sec preferred_lft 85248sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9a:60f4/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.19.1/24 brd 172.16.19.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.1/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I ran the following commands in NMAP to determine the IP:

```
$ nmap 172.16.19/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-25 13:19 EDT
Nmap scan report for 172.16.19.1 (172.16.19.1)
Host is up (0.00022s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
902/tcp open  iss-realsecure
```

```
$ nmap 192.168.43.1/24
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-25 13:19 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1)
Host is up (0.00033s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
902/tcp open  iss-realsecure
```

The NMAP results indicate that `172.16.19.1` and `192.168.43.1` are up and running, but oddly enough, don't show port 22; I still tried to connect to it with SSH.

```
$ ssh user@172.16.19.1
ssh: connect to host 172.16.19.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

```
$ ssh user@192.168.43.1
ssh: connect to host: 192.168.43.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

I also checked whether the virtual machine was listening on port 22, and it seems like it is:

```
$ netstat -latun | grep :::22
tcp6      0       0 :::22           :::*          LISTEN      -
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try stopping the firewall inside your VM.

Comment: @TonyStark I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a firewall. It already contains programs meant to be exploited; it doesn't make sense for it to have a firewall that blocks SSH connections. Moreover, the website doesn't mention any firewall, and there is no mention of a firewall in any website/video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was running on localhost, and since port 22 is forwarded through port 2222 in localhost, you have to use the command: `ssh user@localhost -p 2222`.

Comment: @Machinexa2 Yes, it did.